# I can't get the OR operator to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I do not understand, the OR operator does not work properly.

In below example I am trying to create a hover effect with jquery, which is only applied if the id of the hovered element is not equal to "f1" or "c1"

But as can be seen in the provided example it does not work.
Any ideas?

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".123456", function() {
  if (this.id != 'f1' || this.id != 'c1') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "red")
  }
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".123456", function() {
  if ((this.id != 'f1') || (this.id != 'c1')) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "black")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a1" class="123456">
  <span>a1</span>
</div>

<div id="f1" class="123456">
  <span>f1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: boolean negation 101... `¬(a∨b) ⇔ (¬a)∧(¬b)`, see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: If the id is `f1` then it must be not equal to `c1`, and if it's `c1` then it also must be not equal to `f1` - So what's the point in this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the or's to and's.

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".123456", function() {
  if (this.id != 'f1' && this.id != 'c1') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "red")
  }
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".123456", function() {
  if ((this.id != 'f1') && (this.id != 'c1')) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "black")
  }
});
```

This way, the hover effect will only be applied to elements whose id is not c1 AND to elements whose id is not f1.

Comment: This make sense, How could I have missed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could take [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()), because you need to exclude both, no just one.

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".123456", function() {
  if (this.id != 'f1' && this.id != 'c1') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "red")
  }
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".123456", function() {
  if (this.id != 'f1' && this.id != 'c1') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "black")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a1" class="123456">
  <span>a1</span>
</div>

<div id="f1" class="123456">
  <span>f1</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use `&&` instead of `||`, since it will evaluate to `true` for the *other* case, and thus `true` for the whole expression, *always*.

Think of your logic as `!( (id == A) || (id == B) )`. The simplification of that is `(id != A) && (id != B)`, due to DeMorgan’s laws.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should be using logical AND (`&&`), not logical OR (`||`).

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".123456", function() {
  if (this.id != 'f1' && this.id != 'c1') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "red")
  }
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".123456", function() {
  if ((this.id != 'f1') || (this.id != 'c1')) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white")
    $(this).find('span').css("color", "black")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a1" class="123456">
  <span>a1</span>
</div>

<div id="f1" class="123456">
  <span>f1</span>
</div>
```

Also, you can achieve the exact same result with only CSS and no JavaScript. This would, not only be much simpler, but it is also much more efficient.

```css
.hover:not(#f1):hover:not(#c1):hover {
  background-color:green;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a1" class="hover">
  <span>a1</span>
</div>

<div id="f1" class="hover">
  <span>f1</span>
</div>
```