# Getting OR to work properly on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to disallow certain names to be used on a pipeline.
simply put: " If it is name1 or NAME1, ignore -  otherwise, proceed"
But apparently it is not working properly. (still prints hello, according to the example)
It does work if I put `"params.project != 'name1' || params.project != 'name1' "` Which I really don't understand why.

What am I missing here ?

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'master'}
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'project')
    }
    stages {
        stage ('project stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (params.project != 'name1' || params.project != 'NAME1')
                        println "Hello"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is not duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878682/i-cant-get-the-or-operator-to-work-properly) since I'm trying to understand the logic behind this behavior.

In the end I went with

```
if (params.project!= 'name') {
  if (params.project!= 'NAME1') { 
  }   
}
```

But I believe there is a better way than that..

Update:
I found another way, which is to use `contains`
`if (project.contains('name'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to disallow both values from being used for the `project` parameter, then you need the `&&` logical operator ("and"):

```
if (params.project != 'name1' && params.project != 'NAME1')
```

This will prevent both values for the parameter as desired.

Alternatively, you could also use a regular expression similar to the following:

```
if !(params.project ==~ /name1|NAME1/) // =~ if instead do not want to additionally require type match
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thanks. the meaning of && confused me.     as for the regx, on Jenkins 2.249.2 it doesn't seem to work. says `expecting ) but got !` while not missing the `)` sign

Comment: @Busted My bad on the regular expression; I confused myself between different languages syntax. Updating the answer.